# Naming guideline for namespaces when company has all CAPS

Tags: .net, namespaces, naming-conventions

When using company as a part of the namespace identifier, what should it be called if the company name is comprised of multiple words and all in capital letters?

Please note, company's website, all their documents, and every printed piece of material is using this form, so it is not just matter of branding/logo - this is how company name is being actually used.

Take for example company named "**FASTDATA**"

There is a number of variations that could apply

```
Fastdata.Product.Feature
FastData.Product.Feature
FASTDATA.Product.Feature

MyCompany.Product.Integration.Fastdata
MyCompany.Product.Integration.FastData
MyCompany.Product.Integration.FASTDATA
```

I have been reading [Framework Design Guidelines: Conventions, Idioms, and Patterns for Reusable .NET Libraries, Second Edition](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/microsoft-dotnet/9780321545671) but there seems to be no guidance for such case...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is, somewhat, a matter of choice.  The most important thing here would be consistency.

The "Framework Design Guidelines" book does suggest to use "the offical name of your company or organization when choosing the first part of your namespace name" (via Brad Abrams, on page 56), which would suggest the appropriate choice would be:

```
FASTDATA.Product.Feature
```

This is further expanded upon on page 57, in the section titled "**DO** use PascalCasing":

> If your brand employs non-traditional casing, you should follow the casing defined by your brand, even if it deviates from normal namespace casing.

Comment: Would same rule apply if the company name is not first part of the namespace? E.g. `MyCompany.Product.Integration.FASTDATA`

Comment: @zam6ak Yes - See the second reference I'm showing, on page 57 of your book.

Comment: What chapter/section is that under - Safari Books does not have page numbers :)

Comment: @zam6ak "3.4 Names of Namespaces" - look for Brad Abram's first callout box, and then "DO use PascalCasing"

Comment: Ok I found it under his 3rd call out - there are probably slight layout differences in online vs print editions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first would be the guideline choice, assuming you are creating a project for some company FastData.